# HTML table td border-left color not updating with rowspan

Tags: html, css

I have HTML table with rowspan and I want to `td` with different boarder-left color

```
HTML Code;

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class ="fail-td" rowspan="2">Detail</td>
    <td class ="fail-td">Data 1</td>
    <td class="event">Event</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> <td  class ="success-td">Data 2</td></tr>

</table> 


Snippet:



.fail-td {
    border-left: 4px solid #d9534f  !important;
}
.success-td {
    border-left: 4px solid #5cb85c !important;
}
```

Expected output is `rowspan` second row `td` with green color left border
But result is `td` with red color left border
[image]

Comment: already set class  <tr> <td  class ="success-td">Data 2</td></tr>
but not updating

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dafmfncy/) - seems to work

Comment: We're missing something here, going off the provided markup and styles alone, and as Arkej has demonstrated in the linked jsFiddle, you should be receiving the expected result.

Comment: Please check this ,[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DushyanthaRDDK/h1t0ctmx/9/)  not working for me.

Comment: Ok, so this is a result of `border-collapse: collapse;`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError thanx and it work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `fail-td class name` of second `td` of `data 1` value

```css
.fail-td {
  border-left: 4px solid #d9534f !important;
}

.success-td {
  border-left: 4px solid #5cb85c !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="fail-td" rowspan="2">Detail</td>
    <td class="fail-td">Data 1</td>
    <td class="event">Event</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="success-td">Data 2</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanx and that not my expected out put ,expect out put is Data1 left-boarder with red andData two with green left-border

Answer (score 0):

```
    table tr td:nth-child(1) {
      border-left: 4px solid green;
    }

    table tr td:nth-child(2) {
      border-left: 4px solid red;
    }

    table tr td:nth-child(3) {
      border-left: 4px solid yellow;
    }

   table tr td:nth-child(4) {
      border-left: 4px solid blue;
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Detail</td>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td class="event">Event</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 2</td>
      </tr>

    </table>

<!-- end snippet -->
```